# Cocos2d-x Android : When resuming from Background, Sprite Goes Balck

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I am about to finish my Android Game.. 
Its already available for iOS. Released last week.
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/crazy-jack-the-street-runner/id638121525?mt=8

I am facing an issue in Android. When I resume from Background while playing game, 1 of background goes black. Rest all other graphics are perfect.
If I pause the game, then resuming from background is perfect.
I tried to pause game in `applicationDidEnterBackground`, Game hangs while resuming.
I am not able to add my pause layer in this method.

Any guesses what I can do with this. This is the only bug left, need to release game for Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved in Latest version of Cocos2d-x :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes (Well almost everytime in my case) OpenGl context is removed and again reloaded.
This cause the screen to be turned black and game hangs while resuming.

You should go throught [this](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/news/82). It helped me. Hope this works out for you :)